# Looping through seriescollection and format series fill color

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to work on a code in PowerPoint(PPT) to loop through all the column charts in the PPT and format the each column bars in the series collection to specific colors. It works well when the number of bars is = to the number of lines I wrote for the series fill color.
eg. when I have my 15th line ".SeriesCollection(15).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(250, 10, 10)" but my charts only have 10 columns, it will have error. when there are 15 columns it works.

But chances is the number of column is random on the ppt and I would like to ask if there's any way like For i =1 to seriescollection.count
if i=1, choose ".SeriesCollection(1) color, i=2, choose ".SeriesCollection(1) color and so on...

my code as below, great appreciate if anyone could point me how should I modify the codes and make it works

Thanks

```
For Each Slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each Shape In Slide.Shapes
If Shape.HasChart = True Then
If Shape.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked Then

With sh.Chart

    For Each ser In .SeriesCollection
        .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(10, 10, 10)
        .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(30, 10, 10)
        .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 10, 10)
        .SeriesCollection(4).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(70, 10, 10)
        .SeriesCollection(5).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(90, 10, 10)
        .SeriesCollection(6).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(120, 10, 10)
        .SeriesCollection(7).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(140, 10, 10)
        .SeriesCollection(8).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(160, 10, 10)
        .SeriesCollection(9).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(10, 180, 10)
        .SeriesCollection(10).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(10, 200, 10)
        .SeriesCollection(11).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(10, 230, 10)
        .SeriesCollection(12).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(10, 10, 50)
        .SeriesCollection(13).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(10, 10, 150)
        .SeriesCollection(14).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(10, 10, 200)
        .SeriesCollection(15).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(250, 10, 10)

    Next

End With

End If
End If
Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the code below:

```
Dim SerCount As Long

SerCount = sh.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count

Select Case SerCount
    Case 1

    Case 2

    ' etc...

End Select
```

Comment: Hi Rado, I read about Select Case, but not sure if it's possible to do what I wanted as I couldn't figure the logic for my code to select the right case. what I trying to achieve is, loop all the slides, if has column chart, first column set to the color I have set for seriescollection(1), eg red, then move on to second column, third column... when stop when it reach SeriesCollection.Count.